# making a simple call app in Android but the app crashes

Tags: android

I have been recently trying to make an Android app that simply calls a number . I came up with the following code .main activity:

```
package com.example.irdeesmughal.callapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

public void call()
{
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:03335975321"));
    try{
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }

    catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"yourActivity is not founded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

problem is when I run this app on my Galaxy Note 5 and click the call button, the app crashes.

android manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.irdeesmughal.callapp">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: post the log trace.

Comment: Did you attach call function to your Button in xml?

Comment: yes @Marat i have attached the function with button.

Comment: @smoggers i am new to android , i don't know much . This code was a tempelate i got from internet.

Comment: It may be not only error you need to fix, but you need to pass View as a parameter to the method. So, your call method should be `public void call(View v) { }`

Comment: @Maratstill crashing... :( tried that as well ,

Answer (score 0):

You should request runtime permission on Android 6.0+ [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == 
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
    startActivity(callIntent);
} else {
    snackWithOk(R.string.please_enable_call_permission);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

putting this in your call method may helps:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:03335975321"));
try
{
    startActivity(callIntent);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```